# OnNewIntent not called when notification is hit from lock screen. And intent not passed when notification clicked on lockscreen

Tags: android, xamarin.android, notifications

I built an app which when it receives notifications, launches the main activity, and passes it parameters through and intent.
The intent is passed via the method :

> override void OnNewIntent(global::Android.Content.Intent intent)

This works well when the notification is hit while the device is not locked.

But, when the notification is hit from the lock screen, the method "OnNewIntent" is not called.
I tried getting the intent from the "OnResume" method, but the intent is always empty.

Can someone help please ?

Here are the flags I add in my notification intent:

```
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop | ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
```

For my notification's pending intent, here are the flags I use:

```
PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, pendingIntentId, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
```

Comment: The app will been killed when  lockscreen for a few minutes . In that case the app will restart (MainActivity -> OnCreate). So the method will never been called .

Comment: The app is not killed. I mean, the app is running, then when the user closes his phone, caussing the lock screen to display. Then, a notification is received, which appears on the lockscreen. If the user clicks on that notification, and enters the lock screen, the intent will not be passed. That is my issue

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good, try changing parameter context to Application.Context in the GetActivity method

```
  var requestText = _navigationSerializer.Serializer.SerializeObject(dictionary);
  var intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity));
  intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
  intent.PutExtra("NotificationLaunchData", requestText);
  return PendingIntent.GetActivity(Application.Context, _requestCode++, intent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
```

And need to double click on the notification to open activity when device is locked.